# How to suggest moderators/Privileged users about their Edit, If something went wrong?

Tags: support

I think it's bit of difficult for me to explain this scenario.

I've edited this [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110928/printing-the-records-from-database-inside-custom-page). At the same time [Molot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/molot) done same changes to that post. But unfortunately (by mistake) he missed a tag in coding. Again I did correction but my [suggested Edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30620) got rejected by Clive (Of course it seems like what he said in his suggested edit comment ;))

So what can I do in this scenario. I left comment on this [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110928/printing-the-records-from-database-inside-custom-page) to Molot. Is that valid behavior?

Or can I edit the same question and explain the scenario in Edit Summary?

Please suggest me the best behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "he missed a tag in coding"? Do you mean the opening `<?php` tag that you were editing in? If so, that's _why_ I rejected your edit as invalid - we don't need to add <?php` tags to code that's obviously PHP...

Comment: @clive - Infact user metnioned <?php tag in coding. Please Check user revision  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/57d2b15c-19cd-45ce-b0e5-97b9fba9f567/view-source.

Comment: Yeah, it's not necessary so removing it was the right thing to do

Comment: @Clive oh!! OK Thanks Clive. Infact I did the same changes which Molot done, but my edit got overwrite on second time. so my edit seems minor.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've seen the edits you're making in general, and you're doing the right thing. I don't see many of them being rejected; this one was admittedly quite pedantic, but that's how it goes sometimes :)

Comment: @Clive - ok :) Thanks Clive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

When a user edits a question/answer, they become fair-game to receive notifications for comments directed at them on that post.

So if user joebloggs was to edit a question, and you think there was an error, just leave a comment:

> @joebloggs I think you've made a mistake with foo/bar in your last edit, could you check please?